# How to write XPOST CURL request in php?

Tags: php, curl

I want to know how write the follwong curl (cmd) command in  php curl

annotations.xml is an xml file

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -T annotations.xml -H "Content-type: text/xml"
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/nyc/featuretypes
```